# package ‘syncwave’/‘mvcwt’ is not available (for R version 3.0.2)

Tags: r, package

I would like to install the packages `mvcwt` and `SynchWave` but get following messages:

```
Warning message:
package ‘mvcwt’ is not available (for R version 3.0.2)

Warning message:
package ‘syncwave’ is not available (for R version 3.0.2)
```

In the reference manual to `mvcwt` there is no reference on which version of R the package depends. But the publication date of the package is `2013-11-06`, so the package is not old.

In the reference manual to `SynchWave` one can read: "Depends R (>= 2.13), fields (>= 6.7.6)", so it should work wich my version (`3.0.2`), or?

Why I cannot install these packages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am able to instal **mvcwt** on my machine (also R 3.0.2).  If you can't, it may be the mirror is not up to date.  I always use the 0-cloud mirror (really rstudio.org) because it seems to be the most up to date.

For the second package, it should be `install.packages('SynchWave')`.  You had: `install.packages('syncwave')`.  I was also able to install this package for R 3.0.2.

Comment: I have managed to install `SynchWave`. Can you give me a hint how I can change or update the repository?

Comment: It is actually a mirror of CRAN, I will fix that in the answer.  To choose one, either run the command `chooseCRANmirror()` or add the path of the mirror to the `install.packages()` function: `install.packages('mvcwt', repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')

Comment: Hello Christopher, I vave tried your command `install.packages('mvcwt', repos='cran.rstudio.com/')` and have also changed the mirror manually, but I still get the same message that the package is not available for R version 3.0.2

Comment: Hello again, you have probably Mac OS as operating system, since you have managed to install `mvcwt`, because on the CRAN page of the package one can read: "Windows binary: not available, see ReadMe." I have no idea why they offer the package for Mac OS but not for Windows...